MySQL joins and COUNT(*) from two tables
I have two tables - the first table I am trying to get the total count for a city. On the second I am trying to get the total count for single-family homes. Basically I want the total count of single family homes for a city that are active and published. How do I join these two tables?
This first option works for total count of city
SELECT sum(case when city_id = '4' then 1 else 0 end) ''
FROM #_property
WHERE status_id =7 AND published =1

On the second option works for the total count of single-family homes
SELECT sum(case when property_type_id = '13' then 1 else 0 end) ''
FROM #_property_types

I have no idea on how to get both tables to join.

Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't use # in temporary table names. I think that's SQL-Server.

You're missing GROUP BY city_id in both queries.

What's preventing you from joining these two subqueries ON t1.city_id = t2.city_id?

Clarify your question little easy for joining scenario ... @DavidEllison

Basically I want the total count of single family homes for a city that are active and published. The data from the first table is the total number of properties of a city that are active and published. The second table is the total number of single family homes. How do I join or group the tables so that the answer is the total number of single family homes for a city that are active and published?

Identify the common key - The common key between the two tables might be something like property_id or similar. Ensure you have a column to join the tables on.
Join the tables- Use an INNER JOIN to combine the tables based on the common key.
Apply the necessary filters- Use the WHERE clause to filter by city_id, status_id, published, and property_type_id.
like that.
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM #_property p
INNER JOIN #_property_types pt ON p.property_id = pt.property_id
WHERE p.city_id = '4'
AND p.status_id = 7
AND p.published = 1
AND pt.property_type_id = '13';


Both tables have property_type_id. The table _property has nothing in the column for property_type_id and the table _property_types has data for property_type_id

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM #_property AS p
INNER JOIN #_property_types AS pt ON p.property_type_id = pt.property_id
WHERE p.city_id = '4'
AND p.status_id = 7
AND p.published = 1
AND pt.property_type_id = '13';

The result is a 0. Not sure if its just pulling the result from _property.
